# PHP7 IIS10 Windows Authentication returning various different AD-Users in AUTH_USER and REMOTE_USER

Tags: session, active-directory, windows-authentication, iis-10, php-7.3

I have a very annoying problem as shortly described in the title. As I don't know which settings would make sense to post here and due to the fact, that exactely the same web application was running before on a Server 2008 with IIS 7 seamlessly, I try to explain the occuring misbehaviour as good as possible. I'd appriciate your ideas or hints very much.

Our web application was running for years now on the 2008 server with IIS7, PHP5.6 in FastCGI Mode. We authenticate our users by "Windows Authentication" (NTLM/Negotiate) against Active Directory and therefor just letting the users enter their domain users credentials at start of the session. Actually we allways used named sessions like this: SESS_[TIMESTAMP] and looped the timestamp through the whole applications session untill it was destroyd by whatever - closing, leaving, etc.

Now we migrated the web application to a new Server 2019 with IIS10 and PHP7.4. The application it self works as expected and absolutely with no problems at all. The only thing causing a critical situation is as follows:

I enter the web application on my machine, enter the credentials and - as expectet - am in. I see my Username at the top, everything is ok. As I go through workflows and data manipulations it's also working correctly. BUT: If my colleague in his homeoffice now enters the web application and starts working at the same time as I do, very often I see his username at the top of my browser window and he is me... (???) As we both then press F5 sometimes, the session changes back and forth. As our users (inside company) work with security sensitive data, this is indeed a showstopper.

As far as I can say, I really checked all settings in IIS and php.ini against the settings on the old server and also searched the web for days now. With absolutely no success.

I even commented out the section at my sessions initiation that sets a custom session_name. And indeed I'm not using a custom folder for session files.

The only thing I'm quite sure is that the misbehaviour results out of a misconfiguration in IIS: If I only open a test-file with phpinfo(), I can reproduce the same behaviour. The AUTH_USER, REMOTE_USER and LOGON_USER are changing back and forth between another users DOMAIN\username and mine.

Does anybody have had this interesting but annoying behaviour also? Any ideas or hints where to apply the lever?

Thank you so much for your input.

> New information to my question:
>
> I found out that the most significant difference to the old server is a load balancer! It seams that the **load balancing** causes this problem as the old server was not balanced.
>
> Any suggestions or ideas how to deal with this?

Comment: You can use the network monitor to view the content returned by the server to further analyze the problem.

Comment: @samwu Thank you for that idea. I will check out if I can get further information that way. But I wonder whatelse could I find out that way than what I already saw in the output of phpinfo()... phpinfo() shows me the other username and mine back and forth, without recognizable reason.